# My ElasticsearchDocumentStore() is not initialized

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch-5

```
from haystack.document_stores import ElasticsearchDocumentStore
doc_store= ElasticsearchDocumentStore(host='localhost', username='', password='', index='document')
```

I'm trying to build Question Answering system and using Haystack document store for indexing the document. But i'm not able to initialize the ElasticsearchDocumentStore module from haystack. While trying to create new index in document store from ElasticSearch Document store, but it throws an error saying: "Mapping definition for [embedding] has unsupported parameters"

```
WARNING - elasticsearch -  PUT http://localhost:9200/document [status:400 request:0.008s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)


File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py:315, in Connection._raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    312 except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
    313     logger.warning("Undecodable raw error response from server: %s", err)
--> 315 raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
    316     status_code, error_message, additional_info
    317 )
[RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Mapping definition for [embedding] has unsupported parameters:  [dims : 768]')][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dense vector support has been introduced to Elasticsearch in version 7.0 as preview and in version 7.3 as release feature (see https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch). You'd need to upgrade your Elasticsearch instance in order to use it with Haystack if you're using an older version.